# Shavua SheChal Bo when Tisha Bav is Nidcha (Pushed off)

Tags: halacha, minhag, tisha-bav, nine-days

When the fast of Tisha B'Av is pushed off from a Shabbos to Sunday do the minhagim of Shavua Shechal Bo apply for the whole week leading up to Shabbos (Since 9 of Av is shabbos) or is there effectively no Shavua SheChal Bo because the fast is observed on Sunday (the first day of the week)?
Or, is it a machloket :) ?

Comment: If your an ashkanazi what's the difference?

Comment: I believe for sefardim laundering and showers are permitted up until erev shabbat which is the ninth of av and Tisha bav is pushed off until sunday,but eating meat is still prohibited

Comment: @sam Minhag vs Din. That's a big difference.

Comment: Agreed I just meant the prohibitions are the same for min hag and din

Comment: @sam clipping nails

Comment: Well that's a machlokes see the Magen Avraham and Taz